# Error while installing Android Studio

Tags: android, installation

I am trying to install android studio. I have java as the below command output shows.

java version "1.8.0_51"

However when I install it right at the end of the installation the following error appears.

Failed to install Intel HAXM. For details please check the installation log: "C:\Users\Henny\AppData\Local\Temp\nsvBCFE.tmp\haxm_silent_run.log"

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: The `C:\Users\Henny\AppData\Local\Temp\nsvBCFE.tmp\haxm_silent_run.log` knows

Comment: Thanks should have thought of that! Do you know how to turn on "Intel Virtualization Technology"

Comment: The option should be there in BIOS.

Comment: Check your BIOS (if you have VT in your hardware of course)

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know how to turn on "Intel Virtualization Technology"

Your CPU has to support it first. If it is not available, then you are out of luck. If you got Intel VT, then you shall find the option to turn it on/off in your computer BIOS.

But if you want HAXM for emulator, just go for Genymotion which is VirtualBox based and much faster than stock emulator.